# Ruby Support for SVG

Tags: xml, ruby, graphics, svg

Is there some library or helper to produce SVG graphics with Ruby? I googled a bit and found many, but all seem to be dusty and very incomplete… Does anyone know about some nice, reliable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Does [cairo with the Ruby bindings](http://cairographics.org/rcairo/) fit your needs? It's been used by some major open source projects.

Comment: I don't know. It definitely doesn't look like Ruby code and lacks documentation. I'd rather prefer a pure Ruby solution.